# Binding ng-model to button

Tags: angular, button, ngmodel

I am trying to fetch get,post,put data from httpClient server to angular client on doing that process i took input using **ng-model** and binding it to **button**.I am getting error while creating the button. I think, there is an issue in assigning the input data to variables.

component.html

```
<h1>Products:</h1>
<h1>{{products|json}}</h1>
<h1>Create Product</h1>

Id:<input type="number" (ngModel)="id"/><br/>
Name:<input type="test" (ngModel)="name"/><br/>
Description:<input type="text" (ngModel)="description"/><br/>
Price:<input type="number" (ngModel)="price"/><br/>
<button (click)="createProduct({"id":id,"name":name,"description":description,"price":price})">
  Create
</button>


<h1>{{createResponse|json}}</h1>

<h1>Update</h1> Product</h1>

Id:<input type="number" (ngModel)="id1"/><br/>
Name:<input type="test" (ngModel)="name1"/><br/>
Description:<input type="text" (ngModel)="description1"/><br/>
Price:<input type="number" (ngModel)="price1"/><br/>
<button (click)="updateProduct({"id":id1,"name":name1,"description":description1,"price":price1})">
  Update
</button>


<h1>{{updateResponse|json}}</h1>

<h1>fetch Product</h1>

Id:<input type="number" (ngModel)="id2"/><br/>
<button (click)="getProduct(id2)">
  GetProduct
</button>
<h1>{{getProductResponse|json}}</h1>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductDataService } from './services/product-data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public products:any;
  public id:any;
  public name:any;
  public description:any;
  public price:any;
  private createResponse:any;
  private updateResponse:any;
  public id1:any;
  public name1:any;
  public description1:any;
  public price1:any;
  private getProductResponse:any;
  public id2:any;
  private deleteResponse:any;
  public id3:any;
  constructor(private _service:ProductDataService){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this._service.getProducts().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.products=res;
    });
  }

  public createProduct(product: any){
    this._service.create(product).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.createResponse=res;
    })
  }
   
  public updateProduct(product:any){
    this._service.update(product).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.updateResponse=res;
    })
  }

  public getProduct(id:number){
    this._service.update(id).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.getProductResponse=res;
    })
  }

  public deleteProduct(id:number){
    this._service.delete(id).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.deleteResponse=res;
    })
  }
}
```

server

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductDataService {
  url:string="http://localhost:8080/api/products/";

  constructor(private _httpClient:HttpClient) { }
  public getProducts():any{
    return this._httpClient.get(this.url);
  }

  public create(product:any):any{
    return this._httpClient.post(this.url,product);
  }

  public update(product:any):any{
    return this._httpClient.put(this.url,product);
  }

  public delete(id:number):any{
    return this._httpClient.delete(this.url+id)
  }

  public getProduct(id:number):any{
    return this._httpClient.get(this.url+id)
  }
}
```

please help me out in figuring the issue in **component.html** and **component.ts**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**`[ngModel]`** evaluates the code and generates an output (without two-way binding).

**`[(ngModel)]`** evaluates the code and generates an output and also enables two-way binding.

Instead using **`(ngModel)`** try **`[(ngModel)]`** on your input elements.